# How much room do blue birds and wrens need to perch on?

Tags: birds

I'm thinking I lost the bottoms to 16 bird houses (8 of each) and am needing to cut them again. How much room will the birds need to perch on if I make new ones that fold down this time rather than the plug ones?

Comment: Do you mean how big should a nesting box be ? The standard pattern I have ( for either ) has a 4 X 4" bottom.  The location of nest boxes is more important than size. I have Carolina wrens ( little larger than house wren) and they nest anywhere , like in car bumpers.

Comment: the ledge inside the box itself so that a nest has something to sit on